# Is there any open source WordPress Themes?

Tags: theme-development, themes

I am a WordPress Plugin Developer. But I need to create two custom WordPress themes for a client (Client will sell those themes).

It is hard me to start WordPress theme development from scratch.

So is there any open source WordPress Themes? So I can modify them as my client need.

Comment: Every Wordpress theme is open source. You could try Underscores, or you could Google :)

Comment: Is there any open source themes? Yes, [quite a few](https://wordpress.org/themes). As in **every theme on wordpress.org**.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are referring to starter themes also called skeleton themes.

I have used a couple in the passed.

[Bones](http://themble.com/bones/)

[Underscore](http://underscores.me/)

There are many others out there.
Try and google: "skeleton theme wordpress" for more results

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered to learn how to develop WordPress sites before working with a client?

And you can always go with a child-theme from one of the WordPress default themes or you can start from scratch following this [tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/how-to-create-a-wordpress-theme-from-scratch--net-706) :)